# while(getline()) loop without the empty string after the last pass

Tags: c++

So everytime I use my while loop to read in strings from a file, there's always an extra empty string that is processed last.
    ifstream fin("A7infile.txt");

```
while(getline(fin,line))
{
    cout<<"Original Line: "<<line<<endl<<endl;
    breakup(line,first,middle,last);
    cout<<first<<" :is first"<<endl;
    cout<<middle<<" :is middle"<<endl;
    cout<<last<<" :is last\n"<<endl;
    neww=makealpha(first,middle,last);
    cout<<neww<<" :is the alphabetized line\n"<<endl;
}
fin.close();
return 0;
```

This is what I mean by an empty string

```
Original Line: lolipops And Rainbows

lolipops :is first
And :is middle
Rainbows :is last

And Rainbows lolipops :is the alphabetized line

Original Line:

:is first
:is middle
:is last

:is the alphabetized line
```

how do I get rid of the empty string on the last pass?

Comment: You probably have an extra newline somewhere, you could just check for `line.empty()`.

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::empty` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/)) can be used to check if a `std::string` is empty.

So, check to see if `line` is empty, if it isn't, run your code, otherwise, do nothing.

Example:

```
while (getline(fin, line))
{
    if (!line.empty())
    {
        // Your logic here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to skip empty lines in your file, at the end or in the middle, you could add a check to the body of the loop to skip them:

```
while(getline(fin,line)) {
    if (line.empty()) {
        continue;
    }
    // the rest of your code goes ehre
}
```